# Why is there a difference between the firefox "responsive design tool" and a real life mobile

Tags: html, css, firefox, mobile

I am trying to make a note website. But I noticed that there is a differents between **Firefox design tool** and my own **iphone** [image: It should be like this (firefox)]

But when I test it on my mobile device (iphone 7+) I am getting a other result [image: It should not be like this(iphone 7+)]

I hope someone knows the answer to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

PS.. 
I used https://howchoo.com/g/mte2zgrhmjf/how-to-access-a-website-running-on-localhost-from-a-mobile-phone to acces the website on my phone

```css
<style>
html{
    width: 100vw;
}
/*thead a:link{
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
}*/
nav{
    display: none;
}
thead a:link  {
    color: #262626;
    padding: 13px 1px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.note{
    /*display: none;*/
}
.page-header{
    left: 50%;
}
h1{
    color:#262626;
}  
body{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
nav a:link {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #262626;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
li {    
    float: left;
}
/*dropdown nav*/
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    /*padding: 16px;*/
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {  
    text-align: left;   
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    /*min-width: 160px;*/
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
#bars{
    width: 22px;
    font-size: 25px;  
}

.dropdown-content a {
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 548px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #009fe3;
    color: white;
}
.dropdown-content .active   {
    color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #009fe3;
}
/*dropdown nav end*/
#text{
    display: none;
}
.topnav-right a{
    height: 25px;
}
.topnav-right {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}


li a {
    display: block;
    color: #262626;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #009fe3;
    color: white;
}
.active:hover{
    background-color:#009fe3;

}
.active {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: white;
}
/*form styling*/
.input_form {
    width: 90%; 
    margin: 30px auto; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
}
.input_form {
    color: red;
    margin: 0px;
}
.task_input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 15px; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
}
.date_input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 15px; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
}
.add_btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 39px;
    background: white;
    color:  #262626;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
.add_btn:hover{
    background: #009fe3;
    color: white;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #262626;
    height: auto;
}
tr a{
    height: auto;
}
th{
    height: auto;
}
th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #262626;
}

th, td{
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
}
td{
     border-left: 1px solid #262626;
    border-left: none;
}

tbody a:link {
    background-color: white;
    color: #262626;
    padding: 13px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.select{
    display: none;
}
/*complete button*/
.complete{
    text-align: center;
    width: 10px;
}
.complete a:visited{
    color: #262626;
}
.complete a{
    color: #262626;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.complete a:hover {
    background-color: #009fe3;
    color: white;
}
/*Delete button*/
.delete{
    text-align: center;
    width: 10px;
}
.delete a:visited{
    color: #262626;
}
.delete a{
    color: #262626;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.delete a:hover {
    background-color: #009fe3;
    color: white;
}
.restore{
    text-align: center;
    width: 10px;
}
.restore a:visited{
    color: #262626;
}
.restore a{
    color: #262626;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.restore a:hover {
    background-color: #009fe3;
    color: white;
}
/*completeAll button*/
.completeAll a:visited{
    color: #262626;
}
.completeAll a:hover {
    background-color: #009fe3;
    color: white;
}
/*restoreAll button*/
.restoreALL, .restoreALL a:visited{
    color: #262626;
}
.restoreALL a:hover {
    background-color: #009fe3;
    color: white;
}
/*Edit button*/
.edit  a:visited{
    color: #262626;
}
.edit{
    /*text-align: left;*/
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.edit a:hover{
    color:white;
    background-color: #009fe3;
}
.timer-off{
    color:red;
}
#form3{
    display: none;
}
#completed{
    display: none;
    float: center;
}
#link, #link:visited{
    color: red;
    float: right;   
}
#link1, #link1:visited{
    color: #009fe3;   
}
#title{
    cursor: pointer;   
} 
/*sort function styling for arrows*/
#up {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid #262626;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

#down {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid #262626;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
/*search button*/
#myInput {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 12px;
  color: #262626;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #262626;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
#myInput:focus{
    border: 1px solid #009fe3;
}
/*style login page/register page*/

label{
    float: left;
    color: black;
}
.form-control[type=text], .form-control[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-control1[type=text], .form-control1[type=date]{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
    background-color: #009fe3;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}
.button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}


.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img#randomImage {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
/*form edit.php and login.php */
#form{
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto;
}
/*form index.php*/
#form4{
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
}
/*form register.php*/
#form1{
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1% auto 15% auto;
}
.form-group {
    padding: 16px;
}
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
    position: relative;
}

img#randomImage {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    #form{
        /*height: 50%;*/    
    }
}

.note1{
    width: auto;
}
.input_form {
    width: 80%; 
    margin: auto; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
}
#link2{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
}
#link2:visited{
    color: #009fe3;
}
#link2:hover{
    color: red;
}
.note4{

}
.task p{
    font-size: 16px;
}
.date{
    float: right;   
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: auto;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.edit{
    display: block;
}
nav{
    display: block;
}
.date{
    float: right;
}
#text{
    display: block;
}
.dropdown{
    display: none;
}
.note{
    height: auto;
    display: table-cell;
}
.task_input{
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}
#myInput{
    width: 50%;
}
.select{
    display: block;
    font-size: 19px;
    width: auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #262626;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.input_form p {
    color: red;
    margin: 0px;
}
.note{
    width: auto;
}
.note1{
    width: 70%;
    max-height: 300px;
}
.task_input {
    width: 80%;
    height: 15px; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
}
#myInput{
    width: 20%;
}
table {
    width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To-Do</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/to-do.png">
    <img style="display: none;" src="img_avatar2.png" id="randomImage" alt="some image" />
</head> 
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
     <li title="Home">
      <a href="index.php?Notes=Show" class="active">
       <i class="material-icons">home</i>
      </a>
     </li>
   <li title="Completed tasks">
    <a href="completed.php?Notes=Show"><i class="material-icons">done</i></a>
   </li>
     <li title="Users">
      <a href="index-admin.php">
     <i class="material-icons">person</i>
      </a>
     </li>
        <li title="Add Users">
      <a href="register.php">
       <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
      </a>
     </li>
    <div class="topnav-right">
    <li title="Logout">
     <a href="logout.php">
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out" style="font-size:25px"></i>
     </a>
    </li>
   </div>
  </ul>
 </nav>
<div class="dropdown">
 <i id="bars" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="index.php?Notes=Show" class="active">
       <i class="material-icons">home</i>
     </a>
    <a href="completed.php?Notes=Show"><i class="material-icons">done</i></a>
         <a href="index-admin.php">
      <i class="material-icons">person</i>
       </a>
        <a href="register.php">
        <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
       </a>

   <a href="logout.php">
     <i class="fa fa-sign-out" style="font-size:25px"></i>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hi, <b style="color:#009fe3"> </b>. Welcome.</h1>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="link1" onclick="toggle_visibility('form');"><i style="font-size: 20px; font-style: normal;">Add a task</a><br>
    <!-- form input tasks -->
 <div id="form3">
    <form method="post" action="index.php?Notes=Show" id="form4">
      <a href="#" id="link2" onclick="toggle_visibility('form');"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a><br>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Title</label>
   <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="task" class="form-control1" placeholder="Title To-Do...">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Date</label>
   <input  class="form-control1" type="date" id="dates" name="dates" min="<?php echo $today;?>" value="<?php echo $today;?>"> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Note</label>
    <textarea  name="note" class="form-control1" rows="10" cols="120" placeholder="Description To-Do..."></textarea><br>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" name="submit" id="add_btn" class="button">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>`
   </button>
  </div>
 </form>
  </div>
 </form>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" autofocus="autofocus" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for anything..." title="Type something to search">
<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <!-- title for table -->
  <tr>
   <!-- message for no results found -->
   <!--<p id="message"></p> -->
   <th title="Completed all tasks" class="completeAll">
    <a onclick="return checkCompleteAll()" href="#"><i class=material-icons>done</i>ALL</a>
   </th>
   <th title="Sort By title" id="title"  onclick="sortTable(0)">Title
    <i id="up"></i>
    <i id="down"></i></th>
   <th><select class="select" name="note" onchange="location = this.value;">
  
        <option value="index.php?Notes=Show">Show Notes</option>
      <option value="index.php?Notes=Hide">Hide Notes</option>
     
      <option value="index.php?Notes=Hide">Hide Notes</option>
       <option value="index.php?Notes=Show">Show Notes</option>
     
   </select></th>
  </tr>

 </thead>

 <tbody>

 <!-- table content -->
   <tr>
    <th title="Complete task" class="complete"> 
     <a onclick="return checkComplete('<?=$row['id'] ?>')" href="#"><i class=material-icons>done</i></a>
    </th>
    <td class="task" style="width: auto;"><b></p>
    </td>     
    <th title="Edit task" class="edit" style="float: right; $color;">
      
    </th>
    <td class="date" >
    
    </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>  
</table>
</body>
<script src="java.js"></script> 
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Please share your code. 2. I assume that you chose the correct device to simulate?

Comment: @TimSch yes I selected iphone 7+ as simulator

Comment: @TimSch What part do you need of my code?

Comment: As it's a design/layout issue the according HTML and CSS files would be great.

Comment: @TimSch I added my code to the post but I deleted my php code from the file so thats why there is no input in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your HTML file have a viewport meta tag in its head? It looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Firefox's mobile editor is likely going to ignore this and automatically adjust the scale of the page.

The iPhone screenshot to me looks like Safari is parsing the page in a manner where it doesn't expect the page to be mobile optimised, so basicslly the pixels aren't being adjusted to the viewing distance of the device.

Another thing to consider is that Firefox and Safari do not use the same underlying technology so there could always be variances in end results. That's why it is best to test your websites on as many browsers as possible, which it seems that you have done by testing on a real mobile device.

To read more about the meta viewport tag see [Firefox's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) (it applies to other browsers, too*)

(*Mozilla typically includes a compatibility table if there is an exception or non-standard behavior)

Comment: Does adding it result in Safari rendering the page like you see in Firefox's emulation?